# would `ui.listView->setModel(new QStringListModel(list));` result in a memory leak

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I am currently in the process of learning QT. 
I am using the following code

```
QStringList list;
list << "item1" << "item2" << "item3" << "item4" << "item5";
ui.listView->setModel(new QStringListModel(list));
```

Now my understanding is that `ui.listView->setModel` is being passed as a reference to an object on the heap. Wouldn't this object need to be deleted ? Any suggestions should I be using a boost safe pointer here ? Since every time I update the content of list I would have to call the last statement to update the display.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setModel "The view does not take ownership of the model unless it is the model's parent object because the model may be shared between many different views."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from so little code available, but yes you are creating an object on the heap whose address you might lose and so risk a potential memory leak. You should define yourself either a global pointer to the object and `delete` it when you need a new one.
Even better would be to create a small `class` containing the reference to the current `QStringListModel` and define some methods to create a new one, while deleting the old one.

```
class ListModelHolder {

 private:
    QStringListModel* model;

 public:
    ListModelHolder() { model = 0; }
    ~ListModelHolder() { if(model != 0) delete model; }

    set_model(QStringListModel* model) { this->model = model; }
    delete_model() { if(this->model) delete this->model; this->model = 0; }  
  };
```

Just as an example. You can keep this object at a global scope or as global as you need.

Comment: What if I simply used a `boost::shared_ptr` everytime ?

Comment: @MistyD Usually you don't need `boost::shared_ptr` with Qt.

Comment: why do you create new entity, if qt already has aggregate mechanism? the solution is to pass parent to creating model and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in that case your should delete new QStringListModel(list), but if you slightly change your code it will be done by your listView:

```
ui.listView->setModel(new QStringListModel(list, ui.listView));
```

Answer (score 0):

[QListView::setModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setModel) does not take ownership of the model nor the selection model, except if the parent of the model is the listview. This because a model can be shared between several different views. It means it is usually up to you to take care of the life othe model and delete it manually.

I recommend that you manage that by yourself, with a pointer to the model in your class. This will also enable you to modify the string list that is used by the model.